# I installed pip and beautifulsoup4 but I still can't run it

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I installed pip and beautifulsoup4 but I still can't run it.

I checked that the beautifulsoup4 is installed as :

> python3 -m pip show beautifulsoup4
> Name: beautifulsoup4
> Version: 4.12.2
> Summary: Screen-scraping library
> Home-page:
> Author:
> Author-email: Leonard Richardson leonardr@segfault.org
> License:
> Location: c:\users\mance\appdata\local\activestate\cache\4e8e4795\Lib\site-packages
> Requires: soupsieve
> Required-by: bs4

My Code:

import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')       ###it says this line is the problem

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
print ('comments',tag.comments('href', None))
print ('URL:',tag.get('href', None))

result as below:

> py ex03-01.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\ex03-01.py", line 7, in 
> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4_*init*_.py", line 215, in **init**
> self.*feed()
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4_*init**.py", line 239, in *feed
> self.builder.feed(self.markup)
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\builder_htmlparser.py", line 164, in feed
> parser.feed(markup)
> File "C:\Users\mance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\html\parser.py", line 110, in feed
> self.goahead(0)
> File "C:\Users\mance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\html\parser.py", line 170, in goahead
> k = self.parse_starttag(i)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\html\parser.py", line 337, in parse_starttag
> self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\builder_htmlparser.py", line 62, in handle_starttag
> self.soup.handle_starttag(name, None, None, attr_dict)
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4_*init**.py", line 404, in handle_starttag
> self.currentTag, self._most_recent_element)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 1001, in **getattr**
> return self.find(tag)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 1238, in find
> l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 1259, in find_all
> return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 516, in _find_all
> strainer = SoupStrainer(name, attrs, text, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 1560, in **init**
> self.text = self._normalize_search_value(text)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\mance\Documents\Coding\Using Python to Access Web Data\bs4\element.py", line 1565, in _normalize_search_value
> if (isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, collections.Callable) or hasattr(value, 'match')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'

Comment: Please format your question in a readable way. For code and error messages: wrap them in tripple ` so that they are formatted as code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Update BeautifulSoup4*:

   ```bash
   python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade
   ```
2. *Downgrade Python*: If you don't necessarily need the latest Python version for other purposes, consider using an earlier version like Python 3.8 or 3.9 which might have better compatibility with the libraries and tools you're using.